# How do I follow another user in vk.com?

Tags: follow, vk.com

I have an account in [vk.com](http://vk.com), and there when seeing another user profile, you can see it not only says "friends" but also lists "followers". The option to add to friends is in the left, but I can't find the option to just follow anywhere.

How do I follow another user in [vk.com](http://vk.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Follow profile on VK

- register on **https://vk.com/** in order to create an account and log in
- there are two ways to follow someone's updates on VK:

  - you can just send a friend request to any user, and after this, you will automatically become a follower

    ---

  [image: 0]

  ---

  - the alternative is to activate the notifications about updates, by clicking the 3-dot button and choose **Notify about posts** in the drop-down list (this way you can follow someone without him/her knowing, that you are following him/her)

    ---

  [image: 0]

---

- Note that you won't be able to follow someone on VK if:

  - user added your account to his blacklist
  - user has a private account

---

## Follow community in VK

- following a group or community in VK is pretty much same - there are two options:

  - direct follow by clicking on **Follow** or **Subscribe** or **Join the community**

    ---

  [image: 0]

---

- stealth follow by enabling the notifications

  ---

  [image: 0]